# Newline in fs.writeFile()?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to have FS write to a newline in a .txt file each time the function is called? I have tried \n like in the following example and it doesn’t seem to work:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    fs.writeFile('./file.txt', '\n '+ i.toString(),(error) => {
       if(error){
          console.log(error)
       }else{
          console.log('success')
       }
   })
}
```

Comment: `‘smart quotes’` are not valid strings.

Comment: `'smart quotes'`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like to use the fs.createWriteStream module with flag: 'a' to preserve the old data and then insert it at the end of the file. Maybe that will help you.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const CreateFiles = fs.createWriteStream('./file.txt', {
      flags: 'a' //flags: 'a' preserved old data
})

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    CreateFiles.write(i.toString()+'\r\n') //'\r\n at the end of each value
}
```

Comment: What does the `\r` do? Is that why my newline wasn't evaluating?

Comment: @AxelGreavette Thus, in a text for a line break to be inserted, it was necessary to use `\r\n`. First the cursor should move to the beginning of the line and then down. This is the default linebreaker that Microsoft has adopted. In other words, it is necessary to break the line on windows. This also happens to read the data from the file, in case you want to remove the line break should give a `split(/\r?\n/)`

Comment: @AxelGreavette In case you use `fs.writeFile()` every time you loop, it creates a new file so the best thing would be to use `fs.createWriteStream()` since you want to record several times in the same file without losing information. It does not kill the old data. So the `\ n` you used has no effect whatsoever `fs.writeFile ()`.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try it next time I'm on my PC ;)

Comment: Off-topic but thank you for this! I was so confused to as of why my grammar file for KekkerScript wasn't working